# Retrieve element from page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I want to retrieve the IUPAC name of a chemical on  https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.000.685

I'd like the printed result to return *Benzene* in this example.

The code below pulls all elements with className.

```vb
Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.000.685", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set IUPACName = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-8")(0)
    
    Debug.Print IUPACName.innerText

End Sub
```

This returns:

> EC / List name:
> IUPAC name: benzene
> Substance names and other identifiers

Inspecting the page there doesn't seem to be an identifier to just return Benzene.

Text I wish to pull.
[image]

Comment: Just an idea - Get the innerText property of the 2nd li tag and do a replace with strong tag innerText to vbNullstring?

Comment: Strip out the Mid using `InStr` positions from the prefix `"IUPAC name: "` and suffix `"Substance names"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test on other Office versions but 2019, at least, you can use an attribute selector as follows:

```
Set IUPACName = HTMLDoc.querySelector("[title*=IUPAC]")
    
Debug.Print IUPACName.innerText
```

I was expecting to use:

```
Debug.Print IUPACName.NextSibling.NodeValue
```

So, that latter one maybe what you need on your Office version.

The world of mshtml.dll is quite topsy-turvy as moment.

Comment: This one works on my end `IUPACName.NextSibling.NodeValue`.

Comment: Thanks @SIM. This text node handling is weird and another recent change.

Comment: Thanks again,  IUPACName.NextSibling.NodeValue works here

Comment: @QHarr Would you mind sharing where exactly IUPAC is found in the page? I can only find IUPAC Name, and so im not sure what attribute its selecting.  I asked this question hoping I would be able to apply the same logic to other elements e.g. the CAS number but `Set IUPACName = HTMLDoc.querySelector("[title*=CAS]")` just returns blank. Perhaps I'm using it wrong in this instance but it would still be useful to know for other instances of this I may come across

Comment: `[title*=IUPAC]")` looks for a `title` attribute within an element that contains (*) the string `IUPAC`. You have to examine the returned html, rather than the website html, as the attribute you need changes. The website has it stored as `data-original-title="Name provided according to the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC) nomenclature"`  but this changes with xmlhttp as javascript doesn't run and update the html.

Comment: `[title*=CAS]` is correct to match on node containing `CAS no.:`  I tested it just now.

Comment: Right okay. So looking at the html am I right in saying that I cant really retrieve the CAS using this method? It would be better to get the element by its dd tag?

Comment: You can use .nextSibling to move to the dd from the dt